# Why am I receiving an SQL error with this statement?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am attempting to set up some tables within PHPMyAdmin and have used this statement; Why is it creating an error and not being accepted? I cannot see any obvious syntax problems so I'm not sure what the problem could be. The error being generated is labelled #1064.

```
CREATE TABLE 'users' (
  'id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'username' VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  'password' VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  'email' VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  'dob' DATE NOT NULL,
  'image_url' VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  'name' CHAR NOT NULL,
  'email_private' TINYINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('id')
);


CREATE TABLE 'comments' (
  'id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'comment' VARCHAR(140) NOT NULL,
  'receiver_id' INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
  CONSTRAINT 'receiver_id'
    FOREIGN KEY ('receiver_id')
    REFERENCES 'users' ('id')
);
```

Comment: Escape your column and table name with backtick `\``.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''users' (
'id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
'username' VARCHAR(45) NOT NUL' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using [`MySQL Reserved Words`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) , the way to escape them is by using backticks ` :

```
CREATE TABLE 'users' (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `dob` DATE NOT NULL,
  `image_url` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `name` CHAR NOT NULL,
  `email_private` TINYINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should not use `'` in column name, if you want to use please use ` instead of `'`.
content in `'` means it is a string, `'` always be used for column value not for column name